# A simple win32 multithreading code. Can this work?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi

I want to realize an application having a thread that traverses all files in a disk, meanwhile another thread checking for a condition.

*When the condition is hit, the thread that traverses files quits*.

I have a ***MONITOR THREAD*** like this

```
while(true){

    //--------CHECK CONDITION---------

    if(MEETS_CONDITION){
        //PostThreadMessage WM_QUIT to the SCANNING THREAD

        break;
    }
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

And I have a ***SCANNING THREAD*** like this

```
while(true){

//-------do scanning files------------

//PeekMessage and check if it's WM_QUIT
//if it is, then BREAK.

Sleep(10000);
}
```

The two threads are all created by the ***MAIN THREAD***.

**Can this method work?**

**Any suggestions will be welcomed.**

**EDIT:**

the monitor thread is scanning files not associated to the scanning thread. In fact, in my program, The monitor thread is **opening a specified registry key and checking whether the file pointed by the key exists**. And in the scanning thread, it's **going through the entire disk to collect files that match something else**. So, the two threads go separately and buffering/unbuffering of the files is not separated into the two threads.

The effect is, the scanning thread is collecting files through the disk, and once a specific file pointed by some Regkey is deleted, the scanning thread **stops at once after its ongoing scan**. I loop this scanning procedure because I want the files newly created afterward can be included in the scan as well.

Comment: If the scanning thread is constantly running you can just use a global `bool` to signal it should quit. Otherwise, use an event (or indeed, a posted message).

Comment: Just try. Learning is a process of trying, making errors, correcting them, and repeat.

Comment: you can do this asynchronous from single thread. not need multiple threads. can at once run gui and enumerate/scan files

Comment: @RbMm not great on a slow network

Comment: @JonathanPotter - the open file operation yes, agree. not think about network case at begin. but enumeration files and read data can be done asynchronous. problem only in open request which can hang ui

Comment: The problem with `while(true)` is that your threads will never stop (without forcing them). Moreover, if the monitor thread ends the scanning thread, who is supposed to ends the monitor thread (is that the main thread ?) ?

Comment: @Fareanor there is a `break` when it meets the condition, that will quit the `while(true)` and the MONITOR THREAD will get to the end.

Comment: Ah ok, my bad, I did not pay enough attention to the commented lines.

Comment: What is the condition in the monitor thread ? I know it is supposed to end the scanning thread but if the condition depends on something living in the main thread (or in the scanning thread itself), then the monitor thread is not needed at all. You can just pass a `bool` by reference to the scanning thread and set it to `true` when it is supposed to end the scanning.

Comment: @Fareanor the condition is about the file. But it takes time as well to check the condition. I use multithreading because I don't want the condition-checking slows down the scanning thread.

Comment: Ok, so your scanning thread is buffering the files somewhere ? And the monitor thread unstack the files from the buffer to perform the checking ? If it is the case, your solution will work :) But I'm not convinced you'll gain time compared to doing the checking directly in the scanning thread.

Comment: Don't mix up thread communication with GUI. Thread communication between windows threads should be done with events (ie CreateEvent & friends), not with WM_ messages. Also, never use `Sleep( x )` because there is barely ever a reason to.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the suggestion :) btw, I want my threads to wait between loops to make the computer less-lagging. So how to avoid using `Sleep` when I want my threads to wait between loops?

Comment: By using WaitForSingleObject/WaitForMultipleObjects. Using Sleep() will make your program extremly laggy.

Comment: @Lundin WaitForSingleObject/WaitForMultipleObjects needs a handle passed in. Now I just want to wait for some time then how can I deal with that handle parameter?

Comment: @AkutaHinako Indeed they need a parameter. You _never_ need to "wait for some time". You _always_ need to wait for something specific to happen. In this case, an event would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can this method work?

Yes, and you don't have to do it in a WinAPI specific way using `PostThreadMessage` and `PeekMessage`.

A simple example follows. For more control, look into `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable`.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::filesystem;

// A thread safe varible to signal when it's time to stop scanning
std::atomic<bool> stop_scanning = false;

// a function returning true after a lot of iterations
bool check_condition() {
    static long x = 0;
    if(++x == 1000000000) return true;
    //...
    return false;
}

void monitor_thread() {
    while(true) {
        if(check_condition()) {
            stop_scanning = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void scanning_thread() {
    std::string top_dir = ".";
    while(true) { // continuously scan from a certain top directory and down
        for(auto& dir_entry : recursive_directory_iterator(top_dir)) {
            if(stop_scanning) return; // the monitor thread wants us to stop
            // ... work with "dir_entry"
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    auto monitor = std::thread(monitor_thread);
    auto scanner = std::thread(scanning_thread);
    monitor.join();
    scanner.join();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, delegating the checking by the monitor thread will not save you time as you think but it will even perform worse.

Indeed, the checking will slow the scanning loop but delegating the slow processing to the monitor thread will not solve the issue.
The monitor thread cannot check files that are not already scanned, and as it is slower than the scanning thread, even if the desired file is reached in the scanning process, you'll continue to scan unnecessary files until the (slow) monitor thread had finally reached the desired file too. So you'll gain nothing, even worse, you'll do some extra unnecessary scans.

Even worse (again), to delegate the checking to the monitor thread, you'll need to buffer the scanned files so that the monitor thread will be able to retrieve them and perform the checking for each of them. You'll consequently add some buffering/unbuffering tasks (without talking about the mutex mechanisms that will be needed to avoid concurrent access to the buffer and race condition).

I think it is better to remove the monitor thread and do everything in the scanning thread.
It may look as follows:

```
void scanning_thread(const std::string & filename)
{
    bool found(false);
    bool finished(false);
    std::string current;

    do
    {
        current = find_next();   // For the example, I assumed this function exists
        if(current == filename)  // filename found
            found = true;
        else if(current.empty()) // end of search
            finished = true;
    }
    while(!found && !finished);

    // Do something you want
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make it clear. But the monitor thread is scanning files **not associated** to the scanning thread. In fact, in my program, The monitor thread is opening a specified registry key and checking whether the file pointed by the key exists. And in the scanning thread, it's going through the entire disk to collect files that match something else. So, the two threads go separately and buffering/unbuffering of the files is not separated into the two threads.

Comment: The effect is, the scanning thread is collecting files through the disk, and once a specific file pointed by some Regkey is deleted, the scanning thread stops at once after its ongoing scan. I loop this scanning procedure because I want the files newly created afterward can be included in the scan as well.

Comment: @AkutaHinako Ok, so please include these clarifications into your question so that I can remove my answer. Please note that **you have to make your question accurate and state specifically your use-case/problem**. You cannot ask vague questions and expects an answer to your issue if we have to **guess everything**. I would advise you to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58268156/edit) your question and make it complete, clear, understandable and accurate. This way, we will avoid off-topic answers due to misunderstanding and guesses :)

Comment: @AkutaHinako And by the way, sorry for my off track answer :)